# Evaluating $S=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\int _0^{\pi }\cot \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\sin \left[\left(n-k\right)x\right]dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, summation

How can we solve this problem?
$$S=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\int _0^{\pi }\cot \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\sin \left[\left(n-k\right)x\right]dx$$
As we know **sin** is an odd function and if $m\in$Nature this integral is:
$$\int _0^{\pi }\cot \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\sin \left(mx\right)dx=\pi $$
If summation bounds are finite it is clear the result is zero but how about infinity?
I am sure the result is not equat zero.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\int_0^\pi\cot(x/2)\sin(mx)\,dx=\operatorname{sgn}(m)\pi$ for an integer $m$, we're summing the terms of the sequence
$$a_{n,k}=\begin{cases}
\pi, & n > k\\
0, & n=k\\
-\pi, & n<k
\end{cases}$$
We can consider the following partial sums:
$$S_{N,N}=\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^N a_{n,k}=0\\
S_{N+1,N}=\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}\sum_{k=1}^{N} a_{n,k}=N\pi\\
S_{N,N+1}=\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^{N+1} a_{n,k}=-N\pi $$
Clearly, $\lim_{N\to\infty}S_{N,N}=0$, $\lim_{N\to\infty}S_{N+1,N}=\infty$ and $\lim_{N\to\infty}S_{N,N+1}=-\infty$ so the series in question diverges, and furthermore, it diverges in an oscillatory manner.

Comment: I am sure the result is convergent, that is a part of other problem.